# Unfortunatly...... (everything)...... has stopped

Tags: hardware

At first it was just my LG keyboard that didn't open, so I researched it and I had to factory reset it, after I did that, whatever I opened it'd say unfortunately (app) has stopped. I can't open my home screen, cant open settings, and whenever I try to call it just declines it.
My phone is a LG Optimus F6

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -2):

do a little more research 
learn recovery mode
wipe cache and data partition at recovery if there is an option
if there isnt an option for data do the factory reset at recovery menu
most probably bad created application data cause this